# pass multiple parameters by ajax call to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing multiple parameters to my mvc controller using  ajax call,but my controller method is not hit.I am populating my lists on checkbox check/uncheck.How to pass multiple parameters to mvc controller.

**AJAX POST**

```
    <script>
    var userTilesAdd = [];
    var userTilesDelete = [];
    $("#addTiles").click(function () {
        var screenWidth = 900;
        //var data = JSON.stringify({ 'userTilesAdd': userTilesAdd }, { 'userTilesDelete': userTilesDelete },{'screenWidth':screenWidth});
        var data = JSON.stringify({ 'userTilesAdd': userTilesAdd ,  'userTilesDelete': userTilesDelete ,  'screenWidth': screenWidth });
        alert("Entered function.");
        alert(userTiles[0].TileID);
        var url = '@Url.Action("AddTiles")';
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (d) {
                if (d.indexOf('"IsSessionExpired":true') != -1) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    onAddTilesSuccessful(d);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                errorInOperation();
            },
        });
    });
    function onAddTilesSuccessful(e) {
        $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append(e);
    }

    function errorInOperation(d) {
        $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append("Something went wrong");
    }
    });
</script>
```

mvc controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTiles(List<DashboarTileM> userTilesAdd,List<DashboardTileVM> userTilesDelete,int screenWidth)
    {
     return View();
    }
```

**List model**

```
public class UserTilesVM
 {
public int TileID { get; set; }
public int TopPosition { get; set; }
public int LeftPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Json array

```
 "{"userTilesAdd":[{"DashboardTileID":"10"},{"DashboardTileID":"14"},{"DashboardTileID":"18"}],"userTilesDelete":[{"DashboardTileID":"18"}]}"
```

Comment: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ userTilesAdd: userTilesAdd,userTilesDelete: userTilesDelete,screenWidth: screenWidth,}),
    dataType: 'json'

Comment: replace this instead

Comment: tried you method removed quotes from parameter now also my controller action is not hit

Comment: alert(userTiles[0].TileID); maybe here is your error, i think that should be userTilesAdd  or userTilesDelete, i try your code removing that line and works fine

Comment: try taking off the stringify.  also make sure that the input of your controller method has matching names (the name userTilesAdd in your data object matches to userTilesAdd in your method)